# Getting time from django.utils.timezone

Tags: django, timezone

I am writing a Django app where I have an event model with an `event_time` field and an `event_date` field. I want to check if an event has begun and is ongoing.

If the date scheduled for the event is equal to the date of today, and the time scheduled for the event is less than equal to the time now, it means the event has started; else the event has not started.

Here is my code:

```
context['is_ongoing'] = context['event'][0].event_date == datetime.now().date() and timezone.now().time() >= context['event'][0].event_time
```

I get `True` even if `event_time` is greater than the time now, whereas I want `False` in that case.

Comment: event comes from a django model?

Comment: no need to datetime.now().date() and timezone.now().time() just use datetime.now() its already comes with timestamp

Comment: Yes it comes from a django model which is an event retrieve from the db

Answer (score 0):

Getting position by array from queryset without even check if it have value is a bad smell, suggest dont do that, if you want first element try use function .first()

```
import datetime

event = context['event'].first()
if event:
    context['is_ongoing'] True if event.event_date >= datetime.datetime.now().date() and event.event_time >= datetime.datetime.now() else False
```